# "An AJAX HTTP error occurred" when sending an email via VBO (view bulk operations)

Tags: 7, views

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=42348&op=do StatusText: OK

Running Drupal 7, using amazon SES to send emails. Get the above error message every time I send an email via VBO which is bizzare because the message response code is 200, the status is OK and the email is successfully sent.

Any idea why I might be getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue on VBO](https://www.drupal.org/node/1398502), you likely have a separate module that is stuffing up AJAX.

Try turning your custom modules off and then back on one by one to find the problem.  If it happens with your custom modules all off, try it with contrib modules.